# Spring Inheritance - Annotation

Tags: java, spring

I came across this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition_inheritance.htm) which explains how a bean can be inherited. Assuming that HelloWorld class in this example is exposed as a bean using @Component annotation , how can create another bean which inherits this bean? Can I use extends to inherit HelloWorld bean and add @Component to the new class in order to extend the existing bean expose it as a new bean with additional features?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you make your *abstract* configuration, which is achieved by **not** marking it as `@Configuration`, like this:

```
// notice there is no annotation here
public class ParentConfig {

    @Bean
    public ParentBean parentBean() {
        return new ParentBean();
    }

}
```

An then you extend it, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ChildConfig extends ParentConfig {

    @Bean
    public ChildBean childBean() {
        return new ChildBean();
    }

}
```

The result will be exactly the same as if you did this:

```
@Configuration
public class FullConfig {

    @Bean
    public ParentBean parentBean() {
        return new ParentBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public ChildBean childBean() {
        return new ChildBean();
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**: answer to the follow-up question in the comment.

If Spring picks up both classes, parent and child, there will be problems with duplicated beans, so **you cannot extend it directly**. Even if you override methods, the beans from the super-class will also be instantiated by the `ParentConfig`.

Since **your parent class is already compiled**, you have 2 options:

1. Talk to the author of the parent class and kindly ask him to change it.
2. Change the `@ComponentScan` packages.

To clarify on solution 2:

If the parent class is in the package `com.parent.ParentConfig` and the child class is the package `com.child.ChildConfig`, you can configure the component scanning so that **only classes under** `com.child` get picked up.

You can specify the component scanning packages using the `@ComponentScan("com.child")` annotation on your main configuration file (think application class).

Comment: Thanks ESala. In my case , the class that I am trying to extend is part of a jar and is defined wiith Component annotation. I want to create a new bean which extends it and overrrides one method.

Comment: @PunterVicky I have added the answer to your follow-up question :)

Comment: Thanks again , ESala!