# Cannot get application.yml properties from outside of the main application class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and relatively new to Java. I'm working with the [Github OAuth2 sample application from Spring's documentation](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/github). Out of the box, everything works as expected, however, when I try to move the *facebook()* or *github()* methods into a new class, they cannot obtain the information from the src/main/resources/application.yml file. I have tried with classes in the same package as the main Application class and have also tried putting the class in another package.

*src/main/resources/application.yml (all client information is straight from the documentation)*

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: acme
      client-secret: acmesecret
      scope: read,write
      auto-approve-scopes: '.*'

facebook:
  client:
    clientId: 233668646673605
    clientSecret: 33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
    accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
    tokenName: oauth_token
    authenticationScheme: query
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
github:
  client:
    clientId: bd1c0a783ccdd1c9b9e4
    clientSecret: 1a9030fbca47a5b2c28e92f19050bb77824b5ad1
    accessTokenUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
    userAuthorizationUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://api.github.com/user

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

**The working application**

Directory structure with a single package that contains everything in the main Application class except for the class *ClientResources.java*

*Application.java*

```
package com.github.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(6)
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Ready to Authenticate!");
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter
            = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate
            = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);

        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
                client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId()
        );

        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }

}
```

*ClientResources.java*
    package com.github.example;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;

public class ClientResources implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

**Breaking up the application into multiple classes breaks when it comes to retrieving information from the src/main/resources/application.yml**

I have two packages here:

1. com.github.example
2. com.github.example.providers

*com.github.example.Application.java*

```
package com.github.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter;

import com.github.example.providers.*;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(6)
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Ready to Authenticate!");
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ProviderResources github() {
        return new ProviderResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        Facebook fb = new Facebook();
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(fb.getConfig(), "/login/facebook"));
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ProviderResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter
            = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate
            = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);

        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(
                client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId()
        );

        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }

}
```

*com.github.example.providers.ProviderResources.java*

```
package com.github.example.providers;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;

public class ProviderResources implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

*com.github.example.providers.Facebook.java*

```
package com.github.example.providers;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
public class Facebook  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ProviderResources getConfig() {
        return new ProviderResources();
    }
}
```

**Results**
In the broken source code, the github login still works, however, when attempting to login with Facebook, I get the following 500 error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jul 16 16:10:19 EDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
HTTP URL must not be null
```

**Debugging Results**
While debugging, I noticed that the variables in ProviderResources() are null. I notice the same results when using the *@Value* annotation to set property values. The property values with the *@Value* annotation are set correctly in the main Application class, but are set to null in any other class.

Again, I'm new to spring boot / java and I'm probably doing something newbie-ish. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code that does not work, you are creating a new Facebook bean which is not the Facebook bean from the Spring Application Context.

Since you need properties that are bound to the Facebook Spring bean object you will need to inject in the Facebook Spring bean vs creating a new object that the Spring Application Context does NOT know about.

Remove `Facebook fb = new Facebook();` from the ssoFilter() method and inject in the Facebook object.

One option is to inject in the Facebook Spring bean object:

```
@Autowired
private Facebook fb;

private Filter ssoFilter() {        
    CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(ssoFilter(fb.getConfig(), "/login/facebook"));
    filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
    filter.setFilters(filters);
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I tried tons of different approaches for a few hours and nothing worked. Thanks! Btw, for learning purposes, how can I create a new object and register it with the Spring Application Context?

Comment: I think I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245376/spring-bean-inheritance-using-annotations-bean-reference-back-issue