# Invalid bean definition with name 'employeesJob' defined in class path resource: factory-bean reference points back to the same bean definition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I went through this link : **[Spring Bean Inheritance Using Annotations Bean reference back issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245376/spring-bean-inheritance-using-annotations-bean-reference-back-issue)** and other links as well, but it did not solved my issue yet.

I am working on Spring Boot Batch example. In this example I am getting the below error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'employeesJob' defined in class path resource [com/prateek/job/EmployeesJob.class]: factory-bean reference points back to the same bean definition
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.requiresEagerInitForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:418) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:390) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:189) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.prateek.SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.main(SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beanFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'employeesJob' defined in class path resource [com/prateek/job/EmployeesJob.class]: factory-bean reference points back to the same bean definition
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:226) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.prateek.SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.main(SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

**EmployeesJob.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class EmployeesJob {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean 
    public EmployeesProcessor employeesProcessor() {
        return new EmployeesProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employees> employeeReader1(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employees> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("SELECT employeeNumber, lastName, firstName, extension, email, officeCode, reportsTo, jobTitle FROM employees");
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeMapper());
        itemReader.setFetchSize(200);
        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employees> employeeWriter(){
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employees> fileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        fileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/employees.csv"));

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Employees> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"employeeNumber", "lastName", "firstName", "extension", "email", "officeCode", "reportsTo", "jobTitle"});

        DelimitedLineAggregator<Employees> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

        fileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        fileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);

        return fileItemWriter;
    } 


    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Employees, Employees>chunk(10)
                .reader(employeeReader1())
                .processor(new EmployeesProcessor())
                .writer(employeeWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job employeesJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("employeesJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


# SPRING BATCH (BatchProperties)
# Execute all Spring Batch jobs in the context on startup.
#spring.batch.job.enabled=true

# LOGGING
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

**EmployeeProcessor**

```
public class EmployeesProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Employees, Employees>{

    @Override
    public Employees process(Employees employees) throws Exception {
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue. You cant give `jobName` and `className` exactly same like `employeesJob()`. I changed the Job Name and its working fine now.